# Ramda.js create a filter function by object value

Tags: javascript, func, ramda.js

I'm learning FP and trying to figure this out:

I have a list of users and need to create a function to filter them by name. That's what I tried:

```
let users = [{name: "rod"}]

let nameEq = R.prop("name")

let filterByName = R.compose( 
  R.filter(R._, users),
  nameEq
);

filterByName("rod")
```

This doesn't work because `filter` returns an array. I guess I need to curry `filter` some way, but can't figure it out.

Comment: yes, you were v.close - you wished to partially apply filter, but since data comes last, you can use R.partialRight - http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#partialRight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a `point free` sort of style, how about this approach:

```
const R = require('ramda');

// sample data
const data = [{name: 'rod', age: 25}, {name: 'chuck', age: 30}, {name: 'rod', age: 50}];


// Alternative 1: bake in the name and vary the data

const filterByName = R.compose(R.filter, R.propEq('name'));

const filterByRod = filterByName('rod');

// now supply the data
filterByRod(data); // => [ { name: 'rod', age: 25 }, { name: 'rod', age: 50 } ]


// Alternative 2: bake in the data, and then vary the name

const filterDataByName = R.compose(R.partialRight(R.filter, [data]), R.propEq('name'));

// now supply the name
filterDataByName('rod'); // => [ { name: 'rod', age: 25 }, { name: 'rod', age: 50 } ]
```

Believe you were aiming to do Alternative 2 above in your question.

Comment: Updated answer to offer two alternatives depending on need.